# using python multiprocessing inside django/wsgi application makes defunct apache processes

Tags: python, django, multithreading, apache, multiprocessing

I need a web (django/wsgi) application which must launch muitiple jobs in "parallell" / multiprocess.
So i wrote a django app which

```
import Python multiprocessing module
launch (several) Process
    each processe does its job and writes to que
join
get results from que
```

At first it seemed working fine, but some time later the apache crashed saying: No space left on device: AH00023: Couldn't create the rewrite-map mutex. 
There were a lot of apache related items in ipcs -s and defunct httpd processes. Clearing apache semaphores allowed web server to start normally, but the question is..

**"Is this method (of using multiprocessing inside django/wsgi application) fundamentally wrong? or am I simply missing something? (like just increase number of semaphores in sysctl) "**

my situation in detail..

- I need "many" child jobs and a child job takes "only" ~1 second to
  complete. i.e. a lot of simple jobs..
- Tried WSGI_Daemon, MPM_prefork, MPM_worker with various settings (more/less process and more/less threads), but i dont think it makes any difference..

I need your help! Thank you!

Comment: Do not *ever* consider using `multiprocessing` or `threading` or `subprocess` in a django app. Ever. Use django-celery.

Comment: Using background threads is technically not an issue so long as code is thread safe, but definitely should not be abused by using it to run in the same process as a web application an in process task execution system. Agree that Celery should be used.